# Calling other scripts in PyPI package

Tags: python, r, pypi

I have a Python package that I have uploaded to PyPP. The script calls two additional R scripts to run. I have verified that the required R scripts are also uploaded to PyPI (by physically downloading the latest version and seeing them present in the directory). I also can successfully install and run the main python script.

However, I am having trouble figuring out how to call the R scripts from within the Python script. That is, what directory structure do I use? Here is the command I use to run:

```
$ python_script -f file1.txt -g file2.txt
```

and I get this error:

> Fatal error: cannot open file 'script.r': No such file or directory

In the Python script, here is how I am calling the R script:

```
cmd = [ 'Rscript', 'python_script/Rscript.r' ]
    output = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stderr=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()
    result = output[1].decode('utf-8')
```

But nothing I try works:  I've tried just 'Rscript.r' and './Rscript.r'

I'm at a loss as to how to correctly call this script. It is in the same directory as the main python_script I am running.

Comment: Aren't you assuming that the end user has R installed in the first place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The path here would be relative to where you're invoking `python_script` from, but your R scripts exist in a directory relative to where your package has been installed.

You can use `__file__` to determine the full path to the file which is being executed. By splitting this, you can get a path to the directory where the package was installed, and then add any additional directories/filenames to get a full path to your R script:

```py
import os
this_dir, this_filename = os.path.split(__file__)
RSCRIPT_PATH = os.path.join(this_dir, "Rscript.r")
cmd = ['Rscript', RSCRIPT_PATH]
output = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stderr=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()
result = output[1].decode('utf-8')
```

**Note:** Best practice to ensure cross-platform compatibility here is to use `os.path.join('path', 'to', 'file.txt')` to generate a path instead of `path/to/file.txt`, since not all platforms use `/` as a path separator.

Comment: Thank you very much! That makes a ton of sense and it works now. I really appreciate it!